# multiplication table in android using java

Tags: java, android, multiplication

Implementing a simple multiplication table in android. this code doesn't help in displaying the result. where am I going wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final int a;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // final TextView finalet = null;
    final TextView finale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finale);
    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    final String fromEt = et.getText().toString();

    Button gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gen);
    gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                int a = Integer.parseInt(fromEt);
                for (int voo = 0; voo <= 11; voo++) {
                    Integer sam = a * voo;
                    // finalet.setText(a*v);
                    // finale.setText(String.valueOf(sam));
                    finale.setText(sam);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(fromEt);
```

to

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                int a = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                for (int voo = 0; voo <= 11; voo++) {
                    Integer sam = a * voo;
                    finale.setText(String.valueOf(sam));
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
```

But your according to your code you will see only the last i.e `the number you entered * 11`

If you want to show all you should do something like this:

```
finale.append(String.valueOf(sam) + " ");
```

inside the for loop